# TextBox to TextBox Calculations

Tags: vba

Maybe a simple question but I still need some help with a formula clarification:

Could somebody help me with this:

```
TempCalc = CInt(TextBox3.Value) * (16*POWER(SQRT(CInt(TextBox1.Value)*(1-CInt(Textbox1.Value)))/(CInt(TextBox1.Value)*CInt(TextBox2.Value);2))
```

what is wrong, is the syntax totally off?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `POWER` and `SQRT` do not exist in VBA.

- `Power(x, y)` can be replaced with `x ^ y`
- `sqrt` is `sqr` in VBA

So the following should work:

```
TempCalc = CLng(TextBox3.Value) * (16 * ((Sqr(CLng(TextBox1.Value) * 1 - CLng(TextBox1.Value))) / (CLng(TextBox1.Value) * CLng(TextBox2.Value))) ^ 2)
```

And I recommend to convert the integers to `Long` using `CLng` as there is no benefit in using `Integer`.

So to make it easier to debug I recommend to split the calculation:

```
Dim SqrtVal As Double
SqrtVal = Sqr(CLng(TextBox1.Value) * 1 - CLng(TextBox1.Value))

Dim DivVal As Double
DivVal = (CLng(TextBox1.Value) * CLng(TextBox2.Value))

Dim PowerVal As Double
PowerVal = (SqrtVal / DivVal) ^ 2

Dim TempCalc As Double
TempCalc = CLng(TextBox3.Value) * 16 * PowerVal
```

Comment: @LasseDupont check if it calculates correctly because there were some issues with brackets in your formula. It might not bring the solution you expect. Also check my edit about how to split the calculation to make it easier to debug and to maintain.